# "Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null" error on button click

Tags: javascript, html

I keep getting that error! All of the other posts on this error say to try the window.onload = function, but then I just get the same error, just on page load. Here is the relevant code:

```
var word = ["is", "an", "array"];
var people = ["is", "an", "array"];
var word = ["is", "an", "array"];
var num = 1;
var wlong = word.length;
var plong = people.length;
var qlong = Q.length;
var wordPicked = 0;
var peoplePicked = 0;
var QPicked = 0;
function rand() {
    num = Math.random();
}

function pickW() {
    wordPicked = Math.floor(num * wlong);
    document.getElementById(impword).innerHTML = word[wordPicked];
}

function pickP() {
    peoplePicked = Math.floor(num * plong);
    document.getElementById(imppeep).innerHTML = people[peoplePicked];
}

function pickQ() {
    QPicked = Math.floor(num * qlong);
    document.getElementById(impquo).innerHTML = Q[QPicked];
}
```

Through this, I am trying to get a random element of the array on each click of the button {which for the curious calls rand(); then pickW();} but I keep getting the error on this part of the line:

```
~~~innerHTML = word[wordPicked];
```

and honestly I just have no idea what to do. Like I said earlier, when I turn

```
pickW() {
```

into

```
window.onload = function pickW (){
```

then I just get the same error on page load instead of on click.

EDIT:

```
<button onclick="rand() ;pickW() ;">Click Here to choose a Random Word!</button>
<p id="impword">Ready?</p>
```

relevant HTML code

Comment: You're selecting on a variable, is it defined? Or did you forget to enclose the impword, imppeep and impquo in quotes?

Comment: "cannot set innerhtml of null", that means one of your getelementbyid calls is failing and not returning a dom element.

Comment: Also using your function onClick is fine, the recommendation to use it onload is versus calling it in head when the DOM might not already be loaded.

Comment: i dont know but i think u have to declear function rand (){//stuff} instead of rand(){//stuff}

Comment: All of the "imp" IDs are closed like "impword" and I am pretty sure all of the variables are defined. I dont know why it would be failing though

Comment: Even when I use onload I still get the same error though, that's what I'm saying.

Comment: Please update your question with the actual code you are using, including the HTML upon which this JavaScript acts. The `document.getElementById` calls are failing to return an element, so it may be you do not have an element with that id.

Comment: I added the relevant html but I don't see why that would lead me to an error. And the js code (minus the contents of the array) is the actual code being used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *do* have a `<div>` with the id "impword". That's a good start.

But this:

```
document.getElementById(impword)
```

Means "get me the element with the `id` contained in the *variable* named `impword`". You have no such variable.

What you mean to say is:

```
document.getElementById("impword").innerHTML = word[wordPicked];
```